# Access last item of list

Tags: python, list

This is really embarrassing but I can't figure out why the `list[-1]` method doesn't return the last item from the list.

Here is the series:

```
[df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1]
```

Output is as follows:

```
[2415    False
 2416    False
 2417    False
 2418    False
 2419    False
         ...  
 5614    False
 5615    False
 5616    False
 5617    False
 5618    False
 Name: Close, Length: 3204, dtype: bool]
```

Now I try to access the last element through:

```
[df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1][-1]
```

It still throws the same output as above. I must be doing something wrong.

I can convert this to a series & it works.

```
(df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1).iloc[-1:]
```

But that's not how I want to use it.

Comment: You create a list with a single item and access the last (only) item of it. Try `list(df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1)[-1]`

Comment: Yes that worked. Can you please help me understand why it created a single item list while it shows length of 3204?

Comment: It is a `series` object inside bro, series always shows `Name`, `Length`, and `dtype`.

Comment: @RajibLochanSarkar The item (here a Series) has this length. A list literal is written as `[a, b, c,...]` or here with a single item as `[a]`. Regardless how complicated the expression `a` is, it evaluates to one object which becomes the single item of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is returning a **pandas.Series** within a **list**. So when you access `[-1]`, you are getting the pandas series inside of the list. You can access the last value of the pandas.Series, by calling `.values[-1]`.

Like this:

- access the pandas Series in the list by using `[0]`
- access last value of the series with `.values[-1]`

#### Code:

```
[df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1][0].values[-1]
```

#### Output:

```
False
```

Comment: That worked. Can you please explain what's the reason normal `list[-1]` didn't work here?

Comment: list[-1] returns the pandas series - which is the same as list[0] in this case

Comment: This is a bad approach, why need to access `Series` within `list` when direct access to `Series` is available?

Comment: I guess @ScottC is trying to explain if I am still trying to access through a list, how to do that. But point taken. Thanks. I understand the reason & the series being generated within the list.

Comment: Correct - that was my intention

Answer (score 1):

```
[df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1]
```

This code only return everything as one element in `list`. So, `[-1]` will return a whole thing.

Try `.iloc` without putting the `series` inside a `list`:

```
(df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1).iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using square brackets (`[` `]`) would construct a list. Use parentheses instead:

```
(df1['Close'] / highest(df1['Close'],20) > 1)[-1]
```

Or use functions:

```
df1['Close'].div(highest(df1['Close'], 20)).gt(1)[-1]
```

Or the best is with `iloc`:

```
df1['Close'].div(highest(df1['Close'], 20)).gt(1).iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use `some_list[len(some_list)-1]` which gives the last element

Comment: No this one doesn't work as the list itself was a single item list. So len returns only 1.